# Secure copy of large amounts of directories from Win to Linux and exclude certain filename patterns

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, scp

I need to copy several Tbs of data FROM a Windows computer TO a Linux computer. I can do this in two commands in Command Prompt

Copy only directories and files that are not jpeg or jpg
`robocopy dir_source dir_target /S /XF *.jpeg *.jpg`

Copy securely these to the linux server which is password protected
`scp -r dir_target linuxserver:/dir/path`

Problem. The exclude flag of scp cannot be used in Windows. The first step seems redundant and slows the process. Could this be done in one step?

NB! I cannot copy the files with scp from the Linux server due to network configurations. In addition, the Linux server is used by multiple users but I have a private directory where others do not have access. However, I have sudo privileges only to the Windows computer, not to the Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

What about samba which is the linux compatible with windows file sharing.

Then you can mount the drive in windows, and use robocopy.

In the config file smb.conf

smb encrypt = mandatory in the [global] section

```
[Some Other Share]
    path = /path/to/some/other/share
    guest ok = no
    writeable = no
    write list = @group
    valid users = @group
```

Comment: Thanks for the very nice suggestion. Two questions. 1. The Linux computer is actually a computing instance for many users. Other users should not access to the samba share if I configure it to my home directory, but does this pose any security threats? 2. I do not have sudo privileges in the Linux computer, is this is problem?

Comment: All the shares are controlled in the smb.conf file.  You can delete the whole {home] section of the config.  You provide a read and a write list of users in the config file.  smbpasswd -a username create a samba users and then it prompts you for a password.  I am not sure it you need sudo or not.

Comment: You can also connect Linux to Windows with a simple file mapping because Windows supports SMB.  I use this myself and this may help you.